# How to split file content line by line and save to List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collect

I have to read a file people.txt containing:

```
name | age | sex | address 
michael | 23 | M | germany
rachel | 25 | F | dubai
```

I would like to split the contents of this file and save it to a list of Persons (`List<Person>`), wherein only the name and sex fields have to be set.

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String sex;
}
```

How can I achieve this using Java 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each person is on a new line:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("people.txt"))
     .skip(1) // skip the header
     .map(Person::new)
     .collect(toList());
```

There should be a constructor which takes a `String` to construct a `Person` instance from:

```
public Person(String s) {
    String[] values = s.split("\\|");
    // validate values.length and set values trimming them first
}
```

If only specific fields should be set, you'd better write a static factory method (like `Person::createFromFileRow`) instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
         Files.lines(Paths.get("/your/path/here"))
              .map(line -> line.split("\\s*\\|\\s*"))
              .map(array -> new Person(array[0], array[2]))
              .collect(Collectors.toList);
```

I haven't compiled this, but should do the job.

Comment: I think you might want `line.split("\\s*\\|\\s*")`.  The '|' needs escaping, and it's probably best to include the whitespace.

Comment: `map(array -> new Person(array[0], array[2]))` is a hard-code solution, it looks concisely only in this case without any checks and additional logic